# How can I stop the execution of FixedRateTimer() in Kotlin using a button?

Tags: android, kotlin

I need some help to achieve something that is maybe simple. My code is like this :

```
 class HomeActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)


        repeatAction()

        val stoprepeat = findViewById(R.id.btn) as Button
        stoprepeat.setOnClickListener{
             // I need to completely stop the actions that are repeating from here 
        }


    }
   private fun repeatAction(){
      var repeataction = FixedRateTimer("mytimer",false,2400,20000){
            this@HomeActivity.runOnUiThread {
                   // Stuff to repeat (3 or 4 actions)
            }
      }
   } 
}
```

What I'm trying to do is to stop the FixedTimeRate tasks when I Click on the button.
Also, is there a way to prevent fixedRateTimer from crashing the app after maybe 10 minutes of running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

how about intruducing a `var keepRunning: Boolean = true` in `HomeActivity` that is checked every cycle by `repeatAction()` ie. `while(keepRunning){ ... }` and is set to `false` by `stoprepeat.setOnClickListener`?

Comment: WORKING!    I did as you said, with if instead of while